# Long chrome HTTP request/response time but in wireshark everything looks good

Tags: performance, google-chrome, http, iis, wireshark

We have a two workstation.
First workstation from one city (where's placed IIS server), second workstation from another. Both uses NTLM/negotiate auth.
When page from second city refreshed we have a long loading time 
[image]
From first city same requestes loading faster

[image]

But in wireshark we see that the time from the request to response is only 0.16 seconds (on second workstation).

[image]

What can be wrong?

Comment: It was mcafee dlp policy incluence

Comment: If you already found the answer, post it below and accept it.